# view barcode field in POS(point of sale) session

Tags: odoo, odoo-10

odoo version:10e.
i want to display barcode field in point of sale(pos) session at anywhere on product.[image] Is is possible through module or coding ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this can be possible. To do that you need to add `product barcode` field in view. In that, you need to edit template "**`Product`**" which is located under "**/point_of_sale/static/src/xml/pos.xml** file.

Comment: its working you save